# How to remove default initial second nested field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

HI im using nested_forms for rails. https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form

Is working great my problem is that every time the user edit his info, by default a new field is added, i need that the new field is added until the user clic "add more" in the link you can see usage of GEM but documentation dosent say anything about this..

Here is my code:

```
  <%= f.fields_for :citizens do |citizen_form| %>

        <div>
          <%= citizen_form.label  :citizen, t('generales.citizen')  %>
          <%= citizen_form.select :country_id , Country.all.collect {|p| [ t("generales."+p.iso), p.id ] }, { :include_blank => true } , { :class => 'pca33' } %>
          <div id="delerr"><%= citizen_form.link_to_remove t('generales.delete') %></div>
        </div>

      <% end %>

      <%= f.link_to_add t('generales.add'), :citizens  %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found the answer..

Here is the way to do this.

```
@project.tasks.build unless @project.tasks.any?
```

Wich in my case was.

```
@player.citizens.build unless @player.citizens.any?
```

Hope it helps someone.